Are there only finitely many faces that contain an extremal ray of a closed convex cone?
Let $C$ be a closed convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $l$ be an extremal ray of $C$. Are there only finitely many (exposed)faces containing $l$? (Actually, I care more about the Mori cone.)
Clearly, if $C$ is a polyhedral cone, then only finitely many faces contain $l$.
If $C$ is a circular cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then there are exactly $2$ faces containing $l$: $l$ and $C$.
Here, an extremal ray $l$ of $C$ is a ray with the property that whenever $x$, $y\in C$, if $x+y\in l$, then $x$, $y\in l$.
An exposed face of $C$ is a subset of $C$ of the form $$\{v\in C|\langle u,v\rangle=0\}$$ for some $u\in C^{\vee}$, where $C^{\vee}$ is the dual cone of $C$.
